# Symfony Doctrine Group By Query

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have below sql query running fine,

```
SELECT completed_by, count(*) AS Total
FROM tasks
WHERE completed_by is not null AND status = 1
GROUP BY completed_by
;
```

Em am doing it with doctrine query builder, but not working returning an error.

```
$parameters = array(
                    'status' => 1,
                );

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('log');
$query = $qb
->select(' log.completedBy, COUNT(log) AS Total')
->where('log.Status = :status')
->groupBy('log.completedBy')
->setParameters($parameters)
->getQuery();
```

and getting below error;

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 21 near 'completedBy,': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Answer (score 6):

I know this answer can be late, but I struggled with the exact same problem, and did not find any answer on the internet, and I believe a lot of people will struggle in this same issue.

I'm assuming your "completedBy" refers to another entity.

So, inside your repository, you can write:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder("log")
              ->select("completer.id, count(completer)")
              ->join("log.completedBy", "completer")
              ->where('log.Status = :status')
              ->groupBy("completer")
              ->setParameters($parameters)
              ->getQuery();
```

This will compile to something like:

```
SELECT completer.id, count(completer) FROM "YOUR LOG CLASS" log INNER JOIN log.completedBy completer WHERE log.Status=:status GROUP BY completer
```

Now, You can do another query to get those 'completers', by their ids.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to select a column who is a fk for another table (entity), use the IDENTITY function instead of the column name only.
Example: In your case

```php
$parameters = array(
                    'status' => 1,
                );

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('log');
$query = $qb
    ->select('IDENTITY(log.completedBy), COUNT(log.something) AS Total')
    ->where('log.Status = :status')
    ->groupBy('log.completedBy')
    ->setParameters($parameters)
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong: `COUNT(log) AS Total`. It should be something like `COUNT(log.log) AS Total`.

Comment: Do you have column "log" in your "log" table? If not, then you should probably `count(log.id)` or something like that.

Comment: yes it is id column, i replaced it , but still the same error at `->groupBy('log.completedBy')`

Comment: But it is not error for `groupBy()`, it is error for `select()`. Look at the message: `completedBy,` - you have a comma here, it appears in select clause, not in grouping clause.